How to resolve system-key missing on disk error
While installing and running a processd using zypper am getting below error message, the processd is installed, unable to run as expected, Please help,
 error trying to compare the processd system key: system-key missing on disk
Started process Daemon
daemon.go:502: gracefully waiting for running hooks
daemon.go:504: done waiting for running hooks
daemon stop requested to wait for socket activation
processd.service: Deactivated successfully.


It requires reboot!  If a packages is installed, the kernel package gets updated, so the host needs a graceful clean reboot.
